# Log rotation supervisord day wise

Tags: python, supervisord

I have a python script like follower.py, I am running this script using supervisord and in supervisord conf file for this follower I have configuration for file size is logfile_maxbytes=50MB. After having more than 50MB it is creating file like *.log and renaming the older files with *.log.1, *.log.2 .. . I want to do logging date wise like *.log.2018-11-01, *.log.2018-11-01..., I did found not anything what I search for. Is there anyway to do logging date wise in supervisord.

Here is the [Supervisord Activity log](http://supervisord.org/logging.html)

Here is conf file

```
[program:follower]
directory = /opt/project/src/dj
autostart  = true
command = /opt/.pyenv/shims/python follower.py
autorestart = true
user = some_user
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
redirect_stderr = true
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
priority = 1
```

Comment: why don't you use pythons own logging module? This can be achieved easily with it.

Comment: Hi @Faulander thanks for replay, I am using python structlog only. But I have multiple services like this so for that I am running these scripts using supervisor. output will be handled by supervisor only.